# How to inline CSS in Rails Header with Webpacker assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I would like to inline some CSS within my html. I have done this in the past with **Sprockets** putting something like that in my layouts/application.html.erb

```
<style>      
  <%= Rails.application.assets["application.css"].to_s.html_safe %>
</style>
```

Now I would like to do the same but with CSS assets bundled by **Webpacker**.

I am able to get the path of the file with `Webpacker.manifest.lookup("application.css")`, but I am missing the latest part to get the content and embed it into the layout

**The rationale behind this:**

To improve page speed I want to embed my critical CSS into the header of the HTML. Using Webpack and PostCss tools (PurgeCss). I am able to get a very compact very of my CSS for the above the fold of my home page.

The rest of the CSS is loading asynchronously with the usual packs helpers

**Update 1**

Here is the link to the article I wrote thanks to the answer.

https://dev.to/adrienpoly/critical-css-with-rails-and-webpacker-sprocketsless-part-1-2bck

Comment: Maybe you want to add to the question why you need to include an asset that way.

Comment: sure, just added some rationale behind this

Comment: `Rails.application.assets` is `nil` in production. This is [by design](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/425#issuecomment-382441054).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider having a line in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```rb
import `../css/application.css'
```

and a file `app/javascript/css/application.css` with some useful content.

Then you spell

```rb
<style>
  <%= File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', Webpacker.manifest.lookup('application.css'))).html_safe %>
</style>
```

and it simply works.

Don't forget:

1. To set `extract_css: true` in `config/webpacker.yml`
2. Exec `rake webpacker:compile` after changing these `.css` and/or `.js` files. Or use `webpack-dev-server` for a things like [Hot Module Replacement](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)
3. Turn on (though this is default setting **for development**) `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` (as @Adrien mentioned in comments) for serving `.js` resources by `puma`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm.

Comment: sorry my bad actually after restarting the server I am getting a No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen error

Comment: Which environment do you use? Is there `/public/packs/application.css` file under app's root? Is there `extract_css` option in the `config/webpacker.yml`?

Comment: I am in development mode. 
I do have `extract_css: true` in my `webpacker.yml` config

Comment: If I add in a normal way my pack then in my html it is fetched from `/public/packs/application-[hash-id].css` but this is in development so I don't see it in real in my public folder

Comment: `Webpacker.manifest.lookup('application.css')` does return this `"/packs/css/application-6f00c3af.chunk.css"`

Comment: I could get your solution to work by setting  `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` in my `development.rb` if you want to update your answer. I will try to deploy it to staging now to test in a production environment. thanks for your hints

Comment: I've done a quick test and I can't confirm this. In this case Rails app reads `application-xxxx.css` from `/public/packs/css` by itself and injects its source when constructing html response. This file isn't served by Puma server, so there's no need  for setting `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`. On the other hand `application-xxxx.js` **is** served and in production I've got 404 error trying to access it.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work with webpack-dev-server running. I managed to fix it by setting 
```devserver: {
  writeToDisk: true
}```